# How to get Unicode char on IME window in VB6?

Tags: unicode, vb6, ime

I have a special case when the user is first typing through `IME` by Press Alphabetic `KeyCode` on my `Grid UserControl`, How do I pick up the `Unicode` on IME Window? If the user is typing in English, it is OK. But if the user is typing Chinese or Japanese on IME, the `Unicode` turns into question marks.

```
Select Case uMsg
   Case WM_IME_SETCONTEXT
        If Not wParam = 0 Then
           Dim flag As Boolean
           flag = ImmAssociateContextEx(lng_hWnd, 0, 16)
           If flag Then
              Dim IntPtr As Long
              IntPtr = ImmGetContext(lng_hWnd)
              flag = ImmSetOpenStatus(IntPtr, True)
           End If
        End If
   Case WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION
        Dim hIMC As Long
        hIMC = ImmGetContext(lng_hWnd)
        Dim cf As COMPOSITIONFORM
        cf.dwStyle = 2
        cf.ptCurrentPos.X = UserControl1.ScaleLeft + 3
        cf.ptCurrentPos.Y = UserControl1.ScaleTop + UserControl1.Height - 16
        ImmSetCompositionWindow hIMC, cf
   Case WM_IME_CHAR
       'Send IME Char to UserControl1.KeyPress
       UserControl1_KeyPress(wParam And &HFFFF&)
       Exit Sub

End Select
```

[image]

Comment: I used lngdwSize = ImmGetCompositionString(hIMC, GCS_RESULTREADSTR, 0, 0) but the size always zero. Any idea?

Comment: After I use different Subclasser from Krool, now I can get Right Unicode. Not sure why Paul Caton and LaVolpe cSelfSubHookCallBack doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After I use different Subclasser from Krool, now I can get Right Unicode. Not sure why Paul Caton and LaVolpe cSelfSubHookCallBack doesn't work.

The Subclasser may internally turn Unicode to ANSI or failed to prevent Windows from UNICODE to ANSI conversion.